# org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Cannot click on element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Getting below exception error while running the code in IE browser. However same works fine Firefox and Chrome browser. Can someone help?

I am trying to run the below code in IE browser and trying to click on link "create button" on page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29. But link never gets clicked , same code works fine in Firefox.
can you please advise if I need to make any changes

public class ClickIE {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\Nitin\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 

        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);

        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29");]

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        if(url.contains("wikipedia")) {
            System.out.println(url+" its a internal link - Passed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(url+" its a external link - Failed");
        }
```